# In Tcl how can I remove all zeroes to the left but the zeroes to the right should remain?

Tags: regex, tcl, regsub

Folks! I ran into a problem that I can't solve by myself.

Since the numbers "08" and "09" cannot be read like the others (01,02,03,04, etc ...) and must be treated separately in the language *Tcl*.

I can't find a way to remove all [I say ALL because there are more than one on the same line] the leading zeros except the one on the right, which must remain intact.

It may sound simple to those who are already thoroughly familiar with the Tcl / Tk language. But for me, who started out and am looking for more information about Tcl / Tk, I read a lot of material on the internet, including this [https: // stackoverflow.com/questions/2110864/handling-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-tcl#2111822](http://https:%20//%20stackoverflow.com/questions/2110864/handling-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-tcl#2111822)
So nothing to show me how to do this in one sweep eliminating all leading zeros.

> I need you to give me a return like this: ***2:9:10***

I need this to later manipulate the result with the `expr` [arithmetic expression] command.

In this example it just removes a single leading zero:

```
set time {02:09:10}
puts [regsub {^0*(.+)} $time {\1}]
# Return: 2:09:10
```

If anyone can give me that strength friend?! I'm grateful right now.

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the string, but you need to match after each `:` as well.

Comment: @Barmar Tai the problem is that I know how to make that combination. If you can help me with any answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: This is a time string (hh:mm:ss), right? Why not treating it like this: `clock format [clock scan $time] -format %k:%N`. Only bummer, there is no one- xor two-digit format specifier for the seconds of the minute, right?

Comment: @mrcalvin I did the test with your suggestion, and the feedback was this: **time value too large/small to represent**.

Comment: I just tested with the time string your report above. btw. I confused the meaning of %N, this is for months. there is no one/two-digit specifier for minutes either, I am sry, my bad.

Comment: @mrcalvin All right, what counts is the intention to want to help.

Comment: As for "I need this to later manipulate the result with the expr [arithmetic expression] command": If this is still the case (manipulating a time value), then you might want to use the clock facilities for this purpose, and not run the basic arithmetic yourself. Then you can also sidestep the cleansing step for the leading zeros. See [clock arithmetic](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm#M22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group `(^|:)` matches either the beginning of the string or a colon.
0+ matches one or more zeros.  Replace with the group match `\1`, 
otherwise the colons get lost.  And of course, use `-all` to do all of
the matches in the target string.

```
% set z 02:09:10
02:09:10
% regsub -all {(^|:)0+} $z {\1} x
2
% puts $x
2:9:10
%
```

Edit: As Barmar points out, this will change :00 to an empty string.
A better regex might be:

```
regsub -all {(^|:)0} $z {\1} x
```

This will only remove a single leading 0.

Comment: This will turn `00` into an empty string. E.g. `02:00:00` will become `2::`

Comment: @Brad Lanam Even so, your answer is valid. It will make no difference if you return an empty string. I just need to get the result and calculate. So if you have "00" or WITHOUT both, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're only matching the `0` at the beginning of the string, you need to match after each `:` as well.

```
puts [regsub -all {(^|:)0*([^:])} $time {\1\2}]
```

Comment: It needs the `-all` flag to do multiple replacements

Answer (score 1):

In general it is best to use `scan $str %d` to convert a decimal number with possible leading zeroes to its actual value.

But in your case this will also work (and seems simpler to me than the answers given earlier and doesn't rely on the separator being a colon):

```
regsub -all {0*(\d+)} $time {\1}
```

This will remove any number of leading zeroes, but doesn't trim 00 down to an empty string. Also trailing zeroes will not be affected.

`regsub -all {0*(\d+)} {0003:000:1000} {\1}` => 3:0:1000

Comment: @DonalFellows: Regular expressions will match the earliest possible substring. So, this one will match at the first digit of a number. It will match as many zeroes as possible, as long as there's at least one digit left. Then it will match and capture as many remaining digits as possible. For 1001, it will match 0 zeroes and capture 4 more digits. The -all switch will not find overlapping substrings, so the zeroes in 1001 are safe: `regsub -all {0*(\d+)} 02:09:10:1001:00 {\1}` => 2:9:10:1001:0

Answer (score 1):

the [`scan`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm) command is useful here to extract three *decimal* numbers out of that string:

```
% set time {02:09:10}
02:09:10
% scan $time {%d:%d:%d} h m s
3
% puts [list $h $m $s]
2 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricky edge cases here. Specifically, the string `02:09:10:1001:00` covers the key ones (including middle zeroes, only zeroes). We can use a single substitution command to do the work:

```
regsub -all {\m0+(?=\d)} $str {}
```

(This uses a word start anchor and lookahead constraint.)

However, I would be more inclined to use other tools for this sort of thing. For times, for example, parsing them is better done with `scan`:

```
set time "02:09:10"
scan $time "%d:%d:%d" h m s
```

Or, depending on what is going on, `clock scan` (which handles dates as well, making it more useful in some cases and less in others).

Comment: This works with the colon separator shown in the example, but falls apart when an underscore is used as separator.

Comment: @SchelteBron Of course. But given that we're apparently really talking about parsing times, underscore is really unlikely.

Comment: Underscore may be unlikely. But your solution is more complex than the one I provided. And mine doesn't have this issue, nor the issue you claimed in your comment.